# How to use google authentication with firebase in vercel?

Tags: firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication, popup, vercel

I created a project using next.js, react and firebase. One of the core features of my website is authentication which works through firebase, creating a popup to sign in with google on a button click. This popup works in my local host but after testing out the feature in my vercel hosted website, the popup stays open for less than a second and closes. I haven't made any changes to make authentication work with vercel but i'm guessing thats something I have to implement. I've looked around and haven't found anything clear enough for me to understand as to how I could go about this. Can anyone guide me?

Answer (score 1):

After looking around for a while if you go in the firebase console then go to authentication you should find a settings tab. In that settings tab I had to add the provided vercel url in the authorized domains. I just wanted to make this more clear as I couldn't find anything on the internet explicitly saying to do this.

Comment: Thanks! I found it under authentication -> settings.